# REACT: Best practice for creating components in functional-based react for form inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm developing a large fullstack application. A large part of the pages that we're creating are meant to create database objects, fetch their data, display data, and update data. As such, we have quite heavy, visual-based forms.

I would like to encapsulate different (controlled) form input types that we use (text, email, date, time, etc.) into nice, re-usable components. Importantly, they should be able to hold multiple states relating to a single input (error states, visual rendering states, etc.), and somehow expose its state, so we can grab form-input states and errors to judge whether or not we should submit the states to our API.

We are also using vanilla Bootstrap 5 in the project, and cannot use React Bootstrap, so we must comply by form validation and use in/valid-feedback classes and is-in/valid as well.

What I've tried is this:

1. custom hook with useState hooks that return an object containing states to export, in conjunction with a custom *render* component that takes as a prop the exported state.

ex:

```
const useText = ({initial}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initial)
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])


    return({value, setValue, errors})
}

const TextRender = ({value, setValue, label, id, errors}) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <input id={id} type="text" value={value} className={`form-control ${errors.length > 0 ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`} onChange={setValue}/>
            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                {errors.map(x => {
                    return <span>{x}</span>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

...

const Form = () => {
    const firstName = useText({initial: 'Bill'})

    return(
        <TextRender {...firstName} label={"First Name"} id="firstName" />
    )
}
```

This was great and compact, but would re-render the whole form a lot, and was not optimized when dozens of text inputs were added. This is especially true when this component is adapted to use a **color** input, as the onChange can fire MANY times a second.

2. Entirely self-contained components within custom hooks, which export states AND a render function

```
export const useColorInput = ({initial = '#FFFFFF', options = {labelTop: false}, id, tooltip, label, mode = 'onBlur'}) => {

    const [color, setColor] = useState(initial)

    const inputRef = useRef()

    const onChange = (e) => {

        if(inputRef){
            inputRef.current.value = e.target.value
        }

        if(mode === 'onChange'){
            setColor(e.target.value)
        }
        // setColor(e.target.value)
    }

    const onBlur = (e) => {

        if(mode === 'onBlur'){
            setColor(e.target.value)
        }
    }

    function render(){
        return(
            <div className={`${options.labelTop === false ? 'd-flex flex-row-reverse align-items-center mb-2' : ''} `}>
                {label &&
                    <label className="form-label flex-fill ms-1 mb-0" htmlFor={id}>{label}
                        {tooltip && <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-question text-muted ms-1" data-bs-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={tooltip}></i>}
                    </label>
                }
                
                {/* onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} */}
                <input type="color" ref={inputRef} className={`form-control form-control-color `} id={id} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
            </div>
        )
        
    }

    return({color, render, inputRef})
}

const colorA = useColorInput({initial: '#FFF', label: 'A', id: 'colorA'})
const colorB = useColorInput({initial: '#FFF', label: 'B', id: 'colorB'})
const colorD = useColorInput({initial: '#FFF', label: 'D', id: 'colorD'})
```

This is the most practical solution so far, as it further bundles the components using the render function, and I can render the same HTML/JSX twice with a single state, and the values and other states are returned from the hook so I am able to use the state for form submission.

3. Self-contained react functional component, which only returns the corresponding JSX rendering code

```
const ColorComponent = ({initial = '#FFFFFF', options = {labelTop: false}, id, tooltip, label, mode = 'onBlur', get, set}) => {

    const [color, setColor] = useState(initial)

    return(
        <div className={`${options.labelTop === false ? 'd-flex flex-row-reverse align-items-center mb-2' : ''} `}>
            {label &&
                <label className="form-label flex-fill ms-1 mb-0" htmlFor={id}>{label}
                    {tooltip && <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-question text-muted ms-1" data-bs-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={tooltip}></i>}
                </label>
            }
            
            {/* onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} */}
            <input type="color" className={`form-control form-control-color `} id={id} onChange={(e) => set(e.target.value)} value={get}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the most render-efficient so far, up-until we lift the state from the component to its parent form, which begins to bog down performance on state updates.

That being said, I need to be able to get these stateful variables because I need to update other JSX that use form values in a 'preview' window of the form.

It's also important to know that we also use non-custom components from libraries like **antd** and **react-draft-wysiwyg**, and we have some dynamic input methods, which allow the user to add, swap, remove items (each item having multiple different inputs per, such as an image, an alt-tag, etc...).

I have also used *react-hook-form*, but it started lacking in performance (perhaps I wasn't using it correctly?), and the custom hooks I've created in example (2) were inspired/based off how react-hook-form works, just simpler and uses states instead of refs, and it seems to outperform the way I've implemented react-hook-form for my specific use-case.

**TL;DR**: What is the best way to contain components which contain multiple states, which can be retrieved at the parent-level for form submission, but are also performant in terms of rendering?

Comment: Maybe It's time to consider a state management library like Redux

Comment: You have a point, the main developer would like to avoid Redux and its flavors, but I think it might be time I at least research it and maybe test it to see if it's what we're looking for

Answer (score 1):

*SEMI-SOLUTION*: I'm going to make a fool of myself, but in doing all of these implementations with hooks and memoization, I read that performance increases in production builds - I checked our production/QA build, and sure enough, the *performance issues are entirely gone*. **react-hook-form** does a really good job in our application, and it's pretty much due to development-build qualities that make it inefficient in performance.